# matrix elements correspondence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have a $8\times 8$ matrix $A$, I want to break it into $4$ slices each of size $4\times 4$, this way  I have a cube of $B$ of size $4\times 4\times 4$. The slices are cut out taking each $4\times 4$ submatrix from $A$ going from left to right. My question is the corresponding location of the value $A(i,j)$ in the cube  $B(x',y',z')$. I know that $x'=i\mod 4, y'=i\mod 4$ but how do i get $z'$? Is there something i am missing? 
If an example helps, If i have $B(1,2,3)$, this means that i am in the third slice (slices start from $0$ upto $3$), so the original $i,j$ would be in $\{4,5,6,7\} $ and since i know $1=i\mod 4$, and $2=j\mod 4$ this $\implies i=5,j=6$. How do i write an explicit formula for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full list of rules for converting from $(i,j)$ to $(x,y,z)$ and back.
\begin{array}{l|ll}
x=i\mod 4&& i = x+4\cdot \lfloor z/ 2\rfloor  \\
y=j\mod 4 && j = y+4\cdot \big(z\mod 2\big) \\
z = 2\lfloor i/4\rfloor +\lfloor j/4\rfloor&
\end{array}
Here, $n\mod m$ refers to the unique integer $n'$ between $0$ and $m-1$ for which $n-n'$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: the multiplication factor of $2$  is with the term $i$ because of the way we are making the slices. If we go from top to below rather than leftto right then it will be with the $j$ term? isn't it?

Comment: @Upstart Yes, exactly!

Comment: but why a factor of $2$, is this specific? or will it change if we change the size of each slice?

Comment: @Upstart In general, a bijection between an $n\times n$ square with points $(i,j)$ and the first $n^2$ natural numbers $z=0,1,\dots,n^2-1$ is given in one direction by $z\mapsto (\lfloor z/n\rfloor,z\mod n)$, and in the other direction by $(i,j)\mapsto ni+j$. So the $2$ reflects that $z$ is tracing out a $2\times 2$ grid of $4\times 4$ subsquares. If you instead divided the original matrix into a $3\times 3$ grid (i.e. to stack them to a cube of height $9$), then you would have a $3$.

Comment: okay for an $n\times n$ matrix if i want to convert it into a cube of size $2^x \times 2^x\times 2^x$ then i multiply it with a factor of $2^{x/2}$